# AngularJS app occasionally refreshes with href & ng-href

Tags: javascript, angularjs, href, angularjs-ng-href

Occasionally my AngularJS app refreshes when clicking a link that takes you somewhere within the site. There doesn't appear to be any consistency with this, sometimes it's with `href="/foo"` and other times with `ng-href="/foo/{{bar}}"`

I seem to be able to reproduce this when I click between links in the navigation a bit too quickly and I get a full app refresh.

I would really like to avoid replacing all my hrefs across the site with ng-click that triggers $location.path('foo'); type functions if possible...

Anyone else encountered this issue? I'm using AngularJS 1.4.2

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try prefixing URL with a  # to make angular router work instead of reloading the page? And are you using html5mode for url?

Comment: In addition to Arun's comment, I'll recommend using ui-router

Comment: Prefixing with # works a treat - strange as I tried this last week but must have made a mistake somewhere. Yes - html5mode true. Thank you @ArunGhosh :)

Comment: @Ladmerc Are there a huge amount of benefits switching to ui-router? I'm 12 months into this project and it might be a mammoth task to try implementing this at this stage...

Comment: Yeah there are, most especially if you're  using angular < 1.5

Comment: Ok thanks, will do some research. We've been discussing an upgrade to 1.5 in the near future as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please include some code examples where this is occurring.

Replacing all of your `ng-href` tags with `ng-click` will probably not address the problem. It is a busy task at best.

If you can find a situation where you can repeatedly reproduce this behavior -- interrogate the browser log for errors.

If you cannot reproduce this behavior -- add a decorator delegate to the `$log` service that sends your logs to a logging server. You will probably only want this decorator enabled in Dev and QA. If you have the infrastructure there are great benefits to doing this in Prod.